# Run for loop in parallel (specific)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, multiprocessing

I am writing a system that basically uploads some data to the cloud. This data consits of two parts.

1. raw_data - entire directory
2. config - relevant csv file

Once I upload the raw_data (local machine to Cloud Storage), I fetch the relevant config for that run (from my local machine) and upload it to Cloud Storage.

Problem is, sometimes the raw_data is available, but the config is delayed.

Once I upload raw_data, and come to check if the config is available I use the following logic:

I have a dict, `my_runs`

`print(my_runs)` gives `{'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2', 'k3': 'val3'}`

Where k1, k2, k3       : run1, run2, run3
and   val1, val2, val3 : location1, location2, location3.

I do a for loop over `my_runs`

```
csv_exists = False
attempts = 0
for run,loc in my_runs.items():
    while not csv_exists:
        if os.path.isdir(loc):
            upload_to_cloud()
        elif not os.path.isdir(loc) and attempts == 2:
            email_me()
            attempts += 1
            sleep(1800)
        else:
            attempts+=1
            sleep(1800)
```

As you can see, if a csv is not available, I sleep twice for 30 minutes each, then email myself, then continue to sleep (since pipeline is held-up till I have the config.csv)

The problem here is, if I am on `run1`, looking in `location1`, and am in a deadlock till `location1` is populated, `run2` and `run3` are also waiting without checking if the config is there.

How can I alter this code so that I run this for-loop as a multiprocess, so that I can simultaneously check for the config files in all locations? Upload the onces that are available, and wait for the ones that aren't?

I can't understand how to implement `multiprocessing` or `concurrent.features` in a for loop.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is multiprocessing better/more appropriate than threading here?

Comment: Well that's the answer I'm looking for. Currently trying to implement this by extracting this as a function and use `concurrent.features`